# CSS/Jquery tabs with different images

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying when user clicks on one of the images seen here

http://techavid.com/design/test.html

That the image in background is only thing focused.  All icons are greyed out until user clicks and when they do the colored version of the icon is only showing.  Currently the color image of each icon appears behind the greyed out version when mouseover not active.

Can this be done?

thank you,
paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post the code that applies to this problem. That way the people here can respond faster and better without having to dig through your site to find out what's relevant.

Anyway, here's a simple alternative to what you're trying to do:

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
  <a id="foo" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
  <a id="bar" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
  <a id="baz" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a#foo {
  background: url('foo-inactive.png') no-repeat;
}

a#foo:hover,
a#foo.active {
  background: url('foo-active.png') no-repeat;
}
```

This gives you the hover effect. Do the same for other id's. Add some padding so that the link is wide enough to display the image in the background. Or use `display="block"` and width/height attributes.

Now when someone clicks the image, give it the `active` class that does, looking at the CSS, the same thing as the `:hover` effect. If clicking the image brings you to another page, simply add it in the HTML (`<a id="foo" class="active"...`), if you stay on the same page, do something like this:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // target each link in the navigation div
  $('#navigation a').click(function() {
    // link that you clicked
    clicked = $(this).attr('id');

    // make sure that all the others are not active
    // except for the clicked one
    $('#navigation a').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('id') == clicked) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    });

    // prevent the default link action
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: Alec thank you.  I tried to upvote your answer but i need 15 points reputation.  Definitely will come back and give you props when I reach 15 points.

I implemented your suggestion as seen here
http://techavid.com/design/test3.html

I am trying to have the icons when clicked stay active without going to another page.   Everything seems to work except icons staying active when clicked.  Maybe I missed something?

thanks again  :)

Comment: Alec i figured it out.  Thank you - much appreciated!

Paul

Comment: Alec thanks again for your help.

I wonder how I could make it so when page loads one of the images is active and when another is clicked the one that was active is no longer and the one clicked is?

Also when i added border: none to remove the blue box on click but that did not work.  any suggestion there too?

thank you for all your assistance helping you learn & figure this stuff out.

Comment: If you load the page and know that "bar" should be active, add the active class to that element when outputting the HTML: `<a id="bar" class="active" href="#">&nbsp;</a>`. As soon as you click something other than "bar", jQuery will remove the class "active", and the grey background will be used again. For the border, try `outline: none;` in the CSS.

Comment: Hi Alec

thanks again.  Im still working away on my project and now stumped on how to make the words below each image appear when image is clicked and disappear when a different image is clicked.  Right now 1st: Sun , 2nd: Plane & 3rd: Nano .... all display and they are links.  How to make the text (links) under each image appear on-click and disappear upon different image clicked showing it's own text (link)?

Jquery?

thanks
Paul

http://techavid.com/design/test3.html